# Hide a JFrame and run an other class in the background?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Is it possible to hide my `JFrame` window and start an main method from another class in an action like this?

Here the code of the action:

```java
private AbstractAction start = new AbstractAction("start") {

       @Override
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {


       }
};
```

Comment: I don't think you're using actions correctly...

Comment: Please format your code properly. Select the code you want formatted and then click on the "{}" button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been working on something almost similar to what you are trying to accomplish. 
I have a GUI where the user enters values and then click on a start button to run a program (that uses these values as inputs). When the program starts, I have the choice between:

- hide the GUI and start the program or...
- hide the input fields and show a log text box displaying the status of the program while the program is running.

In both cases, I create a new java thread when I want to launch the program.

Here are the resources that were useful to me:

- Code to create a file chooser GUI: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/FileChooserDemoProject/src/components/FileChooserDemo.java
- Code to create input dialoghttp://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#joptionpaneapi
- Code to create an action listener that launches your program in a new thread:

  ```
  //Handle LAUNCH action.
  else if (e.getSource() == launchButton) 
  {
      JFrame launchConfirmationFrame = new JFrame("Launch Confirmation");
      launchConfirmationFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
      int answer;

      launchConfirmationFrame.pack();
      //downloadDateframe.setVisible(true);

          //if answer=0 its yes, if its =1 its no!
          answer = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
                  launchConfirmationFrame
                  ,"^^^^ ARE YOU SURE YOU WOULD LIKE TO PROCEED? ^^^^"
                  ,"TITLE"
                  ,JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

          if(answer==0)
          {
              buttonPanel.removeAll();
              optionsFrame.repaint();
              optionsFrame.setVisible(true); // THIS HIDES THE GUI FRAME if it is set to false. 

              System.out.println("Launching YOURPROGRAM...");

              //THIS CREATES AND STARTS THE THREAD WITH YOUR PROGRAM TO BE LAUNCHED
                  //More info on threads here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html
              Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                      //Turn off metal's use of bold fonts
                      UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE); 
                      launchYOURPROGRAM();
                  }
              });

              t.start();
          }

          else if (answer==1)
          {
              optionsFrame.setVisible(false);
              optionsFrame.setVisible(true);
              System.out.println("Returning to GUI Frame...");
          }
      }'
  ```

Remember to make your Jframe (here I called it optionsFrame) static so that when you are in you YOURPROGRAM you can decide whether to display it again or hide it.

From your program, you can call:

```
private AbstractAction start = new AbstractAction("start") {

       @Override
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
       {
            optionsFrame.setVisible(false);

       }
};
```

Comment: hey, I just wanted to say THANK YOU you really helped me a lot :D if I can I'll give you something back for it(if you are interested in 3D modeling I could give you some tips ;))

Answer (score 0):

JFrame has a setVisible method which will hide the window as you want.

You could call the main method in your other class statically, though this is a bit of a messy way of doing things.  It is better to have both your main method and the Action call another method which performs the task that you want.

Because you are setting the JFrame to visible in an action and your other method may take some time you will probably need to use a SwingWorker thread, otherwise your interface will hang (Actions are called using the same thread that paints the Frame) and it will not go invisible until the action method exists.  See here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html